# how to give the same style as the back-office theme for people allowed on edition?

Tags: theming, 8

Allowing some roles to edit content, these people get the css from the front theme.

How to set to use the back-office theme for ?

```
 /admin/content
```

and

```
 /node/add/article
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the permission `View the administration theme` and make sure that the option `Use the administration theme when editing or creating content` is enabled on page `/admin/appearance`.

Comment: great , "View the administration theme" permission did the job